# View [layouts.app] not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-5

I have created an application in laravel using appzcoder crud-generator plug-in. i have done everything accordingly but i am getting the above mentioned error. I have a folder named layouts in views folder and this folder has app.stub in it. but when i run the project it gives the following error

`View [layouts.app] not found. (View:C:\wamp64\www\myProject\resources\views\admin\items\index.blade.php)`

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you have run below code if not run it will create **layout.app** path
or manually create **view/layout/app.php**

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Appzcoder\CrudGenerator\CrudGeneratorServiceProvider"
```

Comment: No, it does not work for me. Laravel 5.4.28. I am running the paypal example. http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-with-laravel54example.html